# Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, redmine

When i'm running 
ruby script/server webrick -e production

it gives error

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2010-10-16 11:37:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-10-16 11:37:00] INFO  ruby 1.8.6 (2010-02-05) [x86_64-linux]
[2010-10-16 11:37:00] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:73:in`new'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `create_listeners'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:70:in`each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `create_listeners'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:75:in`listen'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:63:in `initialize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:24:in`initialize'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `new'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in`run'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
        from script/server:3

Using ruby 1.8.6 (2010-02-05 patchlevel 399) [x86_64-linux] Rails 2.3.5 gem --version 1.3.7

Tried for 
gem update --system
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems

still getting error

I have also done this
 gem install -v=2.3.8 rails

still getting error

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you already have a rails server (or something else) already listening on TCP/3000. You'll need to either stop your other server or start this one on a different port:

```
$ ruby script/server webrick -e production -p 3001
```

Comment: It works occasionally.  When i'm restart redime it dosen't work. why?

Comment: Are you running redmine on port 3000? If so, then that's why. Different processes can't bind to the same address/port simultaneously.

Comment: rightnow i'm running it on 3001 port. when i'm installing any plugin & restart at that time it wont connect. if i change port then it works properly.it's not good that everytime i have to change port.

Answer (score 0):

It works occasionally. When i'm restart redime it dosen't work. why?

When i'have changed port to 3001 it works but when i restart redmine it sill get same error.

When i tried to do

rake gems:install

It gives 
(in /var/www/html/redmine)
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 0):

You would eliminate this problem if you make sure to stop webrick instances that you are not using. Make sure that you never damonize or background a webrick instance as this makes it difficult to stop without killing the process. A good rule is to have a terminal session dedicated to starting and stopping webrick that way you never lose track of webrick instances.